# MySQL - Make one record out of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I can't figure this one out.

I have this table:

```
id    component_id     data
1     1                tests@dsaasd.com
1     2                firstname1
1     3                lastname1
1     4                phone1
2     1                email2
2     2                firstname2
2     3                lastname2
2     4                phone2
```

Now I want to have a query that will extract all the data according to the id. I want to have these records:

```
1  tests@dsaasd.com  firstname1  lastname1  phone1
2  email2  firstname2  lastname2  phone2
```

I hope I'm understood....

Comment: There's numerous previously existing questions if you check the pivot tag.

Comment: Instead of directly using a single query, you can use procedure.

Comment: Do you want this data in a single column or multiple columns?

Comment: @bluefeet sorry, i wasn't clear. I meant multiple columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is basically a `PIVOT` but MySQL does not have a pivot function so you can replicate this using a `CASE` statement with an aggregate function.

If you know the values, then you can hard-code the solution similar to this:

```
select id,
  max(case when component_id = 1 then data end) Email,
  max(case when component_id = 2 then data end) Firstname,
  max(case when component_id = 3 then data end) Lastname,
  max(case when component_id = 4 then data end) Phone
from yourtable
group by id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3ec9/1)

The result is:

```
| ID |            EMAIL |  FIRSTNAME |  LASTNAME |  PHONE |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  1 | tests@dsaasd.com | firstname1 | lastname1 | phone1 |
|  2 |           email2 | firstname2 | lastname2 | phone2 |
```

I am guessing that you have a table to associate the component_id with a name so your query could also be:

```
select t1.id,
  max(case when t2.name = 'email' then data end) Email,
  max(case when t2.name= 'FirstName' then data end) Firstname,
  max(case when t2.name= 'LastName' then data end) Lastname,
  max(case when t2.name= 'phone' then data end) Phone
from yourtable t1
inner join component t2
  on t1.component_id = t2.id 
group by t1.id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d02fd/4)

If you have an unknown number of values, then you can use a prepared statement to generate this query dynamically:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when name = ''',
      name,
      ''' then data end) AS ',
      name
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM component;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT t1.id, ', @sql, ' 
                  from yourtable t1
                  inner join component t2
                    on t1.component_id = t2.id 
                  group by t1.id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d02fd/7)

All versions will give you the same result.