# Creating columns with values from a group of values from another column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a database that has two columns in a table called `jos_facileforms_subrecords`. I want to report on: record, value

Record contains a set of unique record values, and values contains the values I want to turn into columns. i.e.:

```
RECORD   | NAME      | VALUE
1        | firstname | Frank
1        | lastname  | Smith
1        | email     | fsmith@email.com
2        | firstname | Sally
2        | lastname  | Jones
2        | email     | sjones@email.com
3        | firstname | Peter
3        | lastname  | Baker
3        | email     | pbaker@gmail.com
```

I want to turn this into a row per record set. i.e.

```
FIRST NAME    | LAST NAME     | EMAIL
Frank         | Smith         | fsmith@email.com
Sally         | Jones         | sjones@email.com
Peter         | Baker         | pbaker@email.com
```

Comment: You need something that distinguishes an email address from a first name.  Do you have any column that does that?

Comment: Yes. I should have added that. There is is a column called "Name" and in that each row has a 'name'.i.e.:

1 | firstname | frank
1 | lastname  | smith
1 | email     | fsmith@email.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - Make one record out of a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726256/mysql-make-one-record-out-of-a-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a PIVOT query.  Other DBMS's have functions for this, unfortunately MySQL does not, so you have to do it manually.  There are several ways to accomplish this.  Here's one that will work for your situation:

```
select
  f.`record` as `record`,
  f.`value` as `first name`, 
  l.`value` as `last name`,
  e.`value` as `email`
from 
  jos_facileforms_subrecords f
  inner join jos_facileforms_subrecords l on f.record = l.record
  inner join jos_facileforms_subrecords e on f.record = e.record
where
  f.name = 'firstname'
  and l.name = 'lastname'
  and e.name = 'email'
group by f.`record`
```

See it working in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/675012/15).

Comment: Genius. Thanks paqogmoez!